# Django - verbose_name from a template tag

Tags: django, templates, django-models, django-templates

I need to display several models name & objects in a template

Here is my **view**

```
def contents(request):
  """Lists Objects"""
  objects = [
    Model1.objects.all(),
    Model2.objects.all(),
    Model3.objects.all(),
    Model4.objects.all(),
    ...
  ]
  return render_to_response('content/contents.html', objs
  , context_instance=RequestContext(request)
  )
```

My **template**

```
{% for objs in objects %}
  <div class="object">
    <div class="object_name">{{ get_verbose_name objs.0 }}</div>
    <ul>
    {% for obj in objs %}
      <li>{{ obj }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And my **template filter**

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_name(object):
  return object._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

This works only if there is at least one `obj` for each `Model` in the database.
How can I get the verbose name of each Model if there is no data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to get a model from the first object in the list. This way, if this object does not exist, you won't get anything.

Try to use a query set instead:

```
{{ get_verbose_name objs }}

@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_name(queryset):
  return queryset.model._meta.verbose_name_plural
```